# ActiveMQ can't be bound to 0.0.0.0 in Wildfly 10.0.0.CR2 in profile standalone-full-ha

Tags: wildfly

When I download fresh copy of Wildfly 10 RC2, and I try to run it using

`bin/standalone.sh -c=standalone-full-ha.xml -b=0.0.0.0`

i receive an exception.

```
08:21:12,870 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.messaging-activemq.default: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.messaging-activemq.default: WFLYMSGAMQ0033: Failed to start service
at org.wildfly.extension.messaging.activemq.ActiveMQServerService.start(ActiveMQServerService.java:307)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.net.BindException: [UDP] /0.0.0.0 is not a valid address on any local network interface
at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:640)
at org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups.JChannelFactory.createChannel(JChannelFactory.java:99)
at org.wildfly.extension.messaging.activemq.ActiveMQServerService.start(ActiveMQServerService.java:247)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: [UDP] /0.0.0.0 is not a valid address on any local network interface
at org.jgroups.util.Util.checkIfValidAddress(Util.java:3522)
at org.jgroups.stack.Configurator.ensureValidBindAddresses(Configurator.java:903)
at org.jgroups.stack.Configurator.setupProtocolStack(Configurator.java:118)
at org.jgroups.stack.Configurator.setupProtocolStack(Configurator.java:57)
at org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.setup(ProtocolStack.java:477)
at org.jgroups.JChannel.init(JChannel.java:853)
at org.jgroups.JChannel.<init>(JChannel.java:159)
at org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups.JChannelFactory$1.run(JChannelFactory.java:96)
at org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups.JChannelFactory$1.run(JChannelFactory.java:93)
at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
... 7 more

08:21:12,875 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
("subsystem" => "messaging-activemq"),
("server" => "default")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.messaging-activemq.default" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.messaging-activemq.default: WFLYMSGAMQ0033: Failed to start service
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.net.BindException: [UDP] /0.0.0.0 is not a valid address on any local network interface
Caused by: java.net.BindException: [UDP] /0.0.0.0 is not a valid address on any local network interface"}}
```

I can run the same Wildfly in full and ha modes without any problem. What do I do wrong and how to get rid of this exception?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I was trying to run it on Ubuntu 14.04 in Vagrant (Virtualbox) as well as on Ubuntu 15.04 on physical machine. What's curious, I tried to run it on another machine with 15.04 and it worked. The machine on which it was working was in completely different, home network. The computer on which it isn't working is a part of big network and has many virtual interfaces (from Docker and virtual machines). I wonder if it isn't the cause of the problem. Does anybody have any clues how to investigate it?

Answer (score 4):

The address 0.0.0.0 does not pass JGroups validation. It should be recognized as all interfaces, but the JGroups treats it as regular IP address. Such interface does not exist in OS. As a workaround you need
to set explicitly the network interface for jgroups in standalone-full-ha.xml. Next reference in  for jgroups settings. 
E.g.

```
<interfaces>
   <interface name="jgroups-intf">
       <nic name="eth0"/>
   </interface>
</interfaces>
```

and

```
 <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="any" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
  ...
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-mping" interface="jgroups-intf" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45700"/>
            <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp" interface="jgroups-intf" port="7600"/>
            <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp-fd" interface="jgroups-intf" port="57600"/>
            <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp" interface="jgroups-intf" port="55200" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45688"/>
            <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp-fd" interface="jgroups-intf" port="54200"/>
            <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp-hq" interface="jgroups-intf" port="7660"/>
            <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp-hq-fd" interface="jgroups-intf" port="7670"/>
            <socket-binding name="modcluster" interface="jgroups-intf" port="0" multicast-address="224.0.1.188" multicast-port="23364"/>
    </socket-binding-group>
```

Comment: This resolved the issue. Thanks for clear resolution